# MessageEvent cannot be resolved

Tags: java, netty

I've used the all-in-one jar from Netty, but MessageEvent cannot be resolved:

```
import io.netty.channel.MessageEvent;
```

GameServer.java

```
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ch.pipeline().addLast(
            new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO),
            new GameServerHandler());
    ch.pipeline().addLast("protobufHandler", new MessagesHandler()); 
}
```

Also, if I remove the MessageEvent to make it work, I can't override it.

```
public class MessageHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, MessageEvent msg) {
        // Print msg
    }
}
```

I'm using the latest release, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no class called MessageEvent in Netty 4. I think you want to replace MessageEvent with Object in your MessageHandler.

Comment: Exactly! I did a search of "MessageEvent" and nothing appeared. Thank you.